# Analytic solution to system of coupled nonlinear differential equations

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider the $n$-dimensional dynamical system for $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)$ given by
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}_i=r_i\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{j\neq i}x_j}{c_i}}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j\right),
\end{equation}
such that $c_i,r_i\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $x_i(t)> 0$ for all $t$ with $x_i(0)=A_i>0$. In two-dimensions, this reduces to the following system of nonlinear ODEs:
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1&=r_1\left(\sqrt{\frac{x_2}{c_1}}-x_1-x_2\right),\\
\dot{x}_2&=r_2\left(\sqrt{\frac{x_1}{c_2}}-x_1-x_2\right).
\end{align}
Is there a closed form or power series solution for $(x_1,x_2)$? What about $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)$? To ensure that the constraint $x_i(t)>0$ is met, I have found that $c_i$ should be small. Note that the steady states are
\begin{align}
x_1^{*}&=\frac{c_2}{(c_1+c_2)^2},\\
x_2^{*}&=\frac{c_1}{(c_1+c_2)^2},
\end{align}
for the two-dimensional system and
\begin{align}
x_1^{*}&=\frac{2\left(c_{2}+c_{3}-c_{1}\right)}{\left(c_{1}+c_{2}+c_{3}\right)^{2}},\\
x_2^{*}&=\frac{2\left(c_{1}+c_{3}-c_{2}\right)}{\left(c_{1}+c_{2}+c_{3}\right)^{2}},\\
x_3^{*}&=\frac{2\left(c_{1}+c_{2}-c_{3}\right)}{\left(c_{1}+c_{2}+c_{3}\right)^{2}},
\end{align}
for the three-dimensional system. I haven't found the steady state for $n$-dimensions but one could conjecture $\left(\sum_{j}c_j\right)^2$ to be the denominator. Refer to the plot below for a numerical solution.
[image: Numerical Solution]

Comment: One approach commonly used is perturbation theory: first solve for the steady states of the system, interpret the general state of a system as a perturbation from the steady state, derive the dynamical system for the perturbation variables, and solve that. Sometimes, the perturbation system can be cleanly solved, but often people assume the perturbation is small to some order O, so that they can use Taylor series expansion and make the equations simpler. If I get time, I'll try myself later

Comment: If $r_i=r_j$ and $c_i = c_j$, perhaps we can hope there is analytic solution!